# WPF .NET 4 DataGrid Column Performance

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid

I am using the .NET 4 WPF DataGrid and notice poor vertical scrolling performance when using a large number of columns. Here is what i did to test this:

1. Enable Virtualization (VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling")
2. Embed the DataGrid in a simple Grid layout and there are no other controls in this window
3. The columns have no custom formatting, no images - just simple text
4. I am running on a pretty good computer. win7(64-bit) on quad core 3.2gz with 8gb ram and radeon 7800 series card
5. Tests with Perforator don't show anything bad like software rendering, etc

Here are some results:

- 100 rows     x   5 cols : Smooth scrolling
- 100,000 rows x   5 cols : Smooth scrolling
- 100 rows     x  75 cols : Very poor scroll performance
- 100,000 rows x  75 cols : Completely frozen

What can i do to improve vertical scrolling performance when i have a large number of columns (~75 - 100)?

Thanks

Comment: Does 75 columns make sense, even it it worked flawlessly? I suggest using only important columns by default and showing an alphabetically sorted list of optional columns as checkboxes to the side of a grid which can be made visible on request by user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing two very important properties:

- [EnableColumnVirtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablecolumnvirtualization.aspx) - Default value is false
- [EnableRowVirtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization.aspx) - Default value is true

Enable both of them and see if that makes a difference.  It should help.

I have about 20 or so columns with about 2,500 rows and I haven't see performance issues, but it 75 columns definitely seems like a lot.  You might want to investigate adding a right-click enable/disable columns in the header (similar to excel).

Comment: Thank you. These 2 properties helped a lot. Disabling virtualizingstackpanel and enabling these two properties made a big difference. I am now able to manage 75 cols x 10,000 rows. My app is an excel like app and users typically choose between 75 - 150 columns out of a total of 300. They extend the app across multiple monitors. Hence, this example is actually a real life scenario. This change now works for upto 90 columns. Wonder if there is a way i can  make it work for 150. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Rhino, I have the same situation, do you mean the workaround is EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" ? In my case it almost stops, scrolls very slow

Comment: thanks @daub815 for response, but what you mean "turn off the stackpanel virtualizing for the pane"? do you mean change itempanel to stackpanel expect of virtualized onr?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt I would need to see the rest of your xaml to understand the difference between this question and yours.  Perhaps you should post another stackoverflow question.